# Variable product stock quantity

Tags: woocommerce

We have 2 attributes for sizes on our WooCommerce store - a bikini top and bikini bottom. We allow users to mix and match sizes. E.g. they can pick a Small top and a Medium bottom

[image]

We have a problem with stock control. If a customer buys a Small top and a Medium bottom then we can only reduce the stock quantity by 1. This wouldn't be right as we'd only be selling half the product. Has anyone come across this before? Or any plugins out there for this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: This is a real development particular case… I don't know if some plugin exist already for that, but everything is possible in woocommerce. Have you looked at, or searched for composite products? This can't be handled by a normal variable product.